# how to get ajax posted value in controller action in mvc4 asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building Event calendar in mvc4, I have build simple calendar in JavaScript using JQuery.  I am able to get date by clicking respective day of month.  I want to fetch this date in one action of the controller so that I can use this date to save in the database.

HomeController: `index.cshtml`:

```
function getDate() {

                $('.cal_daybox').on('click', function () {
                    var timestamp = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
                    var day = new Date(timestamp);
                    alert("You clicked " + day.toDateString());

                    var url = '@Url.Content("~/Events/Index")';
                   // window.location = url;

                    var date =day.toDateString();


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: date,
                        dataType:"json"
                    });
                    return false;
                });
                }
```

Now I am able to get this date in debugger, but I want to display this date in other view.  Can you please tell me how can I pass this date value to controller, because code below is not working?

`Eventscontroller.cs`:

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult Index(string date)
    {

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(date, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")` instead of `@Url.Content()`. `@Url.Content` is for accessing files not controller actions. Alternatively, you can use `@Url.RouteUrl` if you have a route defined for that action.

Also, you may want to change `data` to use `data: { date: day.toDateString() }` to match the action's parameter.

Comment: You're very welcome. Remember to mark the answer accepted (green check to the left) for reference to future visitors (as well as keep your accept rating up and earn a couple of pints). ;-) Also, welcome to StackOverflow!